# awk remove before match but after empty line

Tags: bash, awk

I didn't find the exact similar question, so i need to ask:

I have a file [gist](https://gist.github.com/PFAhard/98f2a9ba65d83481c847f2ca5072f6ea) :

```
...
must_be_intact

bad_line
bad_line
bad_line
match_line
...
```

I use awk to remove everything before the match but after a space:

```sh
'NR==FNR{if (/match_line/) { 
    i=0;
    while(1) {
        if (NR-i==/^\s*$/) break; 
        del[NR-i]; 
        i=i-1; 
        next
        }
    }
} !(FNR in del)'
```

But this does not work correctly. Help improve this code, or you can advise another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overcomplicated it.

You can just use `tac + awk + tac` operations:

```sh
tac file | awk '/^match_line$/,!NF{next} 1' | tac
must_be_intact

must_be_intact
must_be_intact
must_be_intact

must_be_intact
must_be_intact
must_be_intact

must_be_intact

must_be_intact

must_be_intact
must_be_intact

must_be_intact
must_be_intact
must_be_intact
```

This `awk` uses a range from `NF==0` (indicating empty line) to a line that just has `match_line` and uses `next` in action block to skip that part.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting `RS`(record separator) as 1 or more occurrences of new lines till match_line and in main program; substituting first new line with NULL and then printing the lines as per RS.

```
awk -v RS='\n+.*match_line' '{sub(/\n/,"")}1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ sed '/^$/,/match_line/{/match_line/!d}' txt
...
must_be_intact
match_line
...
```

Or

```sh
awk -v m="match_line" '{ if($0 ~ /^$/) { while($0 != m) getline } print }' txt
```

Which yields the same output. I can edit/elaborate later if you want, now I have to go! :)